# Как сравнить текущую дату по часовому интервалу?

Tags: c#

Есть метод, который работает в цикле. И я хочу чтобы в промежутке между 15-55 и 16-05 он не работал. Я сделал вот так

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
if (date.Hour>=15 && date.Minute>=55 && date.Hour<=16 && date.Hour<=05)
return
```

Решение мне кажется каким то топорным. Подскажите как можно упростить конструкцию выше?

Comment: Решение не то чтобы топорное, оно просто нерабочее, потому что минуты не могут быть одновременно более 55 и  менее 5

Comment: Просто создайте пару TimeSpan и проверяйте, что date.Time находится между ними

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно поподробнее:

Comment: `if ((date.Hour==15 && date.Minute>=55) || (date.Hour==16 && date.Minute<=05))`

Comment: Можно, добавил ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать как-то так:

```
private static readonly TimeSpan quietTimeStart = new TimeSpan(15, 55, 00);
private static readonly TimeSpan quietTimeEnd = new TimeSpan(16, 05, 00);
private static bool IsQuietTime(TimeSpan time)
{
    return time >= quietTimeStart && time <= quietTimeEnd;
}
```

И в коде метода:

```
if (IsQuietTime(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)) return;
```

Comment: Я бы использовал utc, а то на разных серверах в разных часовых поясах это будет разным временем.

Comment: @tym32167, оставим это на совести ТС, моя задача показать путь, а не дать готовое решение, которое учтет все нюансы :)